# Lights beyond the fourth do not appear?

Tags: unity, lighting, unity-urp

In my scene there are 6 point lights. But 2 of them do not illuminate my floor plane.

If I disable any of the working lights, then one of the non-working lights starts working.

It's like my level can't take more than 4 point lights? I'm using Unity's URP. How can I solve this?

[image: 6 point lights only 4 glowing spots on ground]

Answer (score 1):

Let me tell you URP limitations:

- Main Directional Light 1
- Per Object: 8 (4 for GLES2). Can be point,    spot, and directional
  Lights.
- Per Camera: 256 (32 on mobile    platforms)

For more info: [URP vs Build In Render Pipeline](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@7.1/manual/universalrp-builtin-feature-comparison.html)

Comment: How to be like that? How to solve this? Is there add-on can solve this? I never thought on a problem like this!!

Comment: @user43474 Perhaps you should bake your lighting.

Comment: I saw "REALTIME LIGHTING in Unity" tutorial from Brackeys. He used 9 light objects for his small scene!! No single problem like I have here!